# Bisection on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, bisection

I am an engineering student and we are required to take a Computational Method class. I was working on my MATLAB assignment and I have seem to have run into a problem that I cannot troubleshoot. I am a novice to MATLAB so the solution may seem simple and I am just being dumb.

The issue is when I try to plug in decimals into a function I get an error in the command window that says "Attempted to access y(17.5); index must be a positive integer or logical." I understand that the issue is the 17.5 but I need to be able to get values for non-integers or else the bisection will not work.

Here is the code for the Program:

```
clc
clear
x=-25:.5:25;
y=-x.^2+4*x+300;
plot(x,y);
grid on;
hold on
disp('Look at the graph, and select the upper and lower bounds to find the POSITIVE root.')
x_min=input('The lower bound is: ');
x_max=input('The upper bound is: ');
E_a=1;
while E_a >= 0.01
    x_mid=((x_min + x_max)/2)
    if (y(x_mid))*(y(x_max)) < 0
        x_max = x_mid
    end
end
```

For my x_min I used 15, and 20 for x_max

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Hi, wlouis. Welcome to stackoverflow. :) Have you gone through any MATLAB tutorials? In particular, do you understand what the line `y=-x.^2+4*x+300;` is doing? I'm interested to know if you've ever programmed before as well, just so I know what level you're at.

Comment: I am aware of what it does. It's a function for what the x values get plugged into. At least that is my understanding of it. This is my first and only programming class I have to take. I am a beginner to this, but do understand the syntax I used.

Comment: `y` itself isn't a function. It's actually a list of numbers (i.e. an array) that you computed from the array `x`. You can try entering `x=-25:.5:25` into the command line without a `;` to see what `x` is, and then `y=-x.^2+4*x+300` to see what `y` is. `y(1)` refers to the 1st element of `y`, `y(2)` is the 2nd element, and so forth. It doesn't make sense to ask for the 17.5th element of `y`. You should instead be computing `y_mid` and `y_max` from `x_mid` and `x_max` every time you go through your while loop.

Comment: This is a good MATLAB video tutorial if you are looking for one: http://www.mathworks.com/videos/getting-started-with-matlab-68985.html

Comment: Okay so instead of relying on the matrix to pull out values like I thought it would, I must make a line like    `(x_max).^2+4*(x_max)+300`  so that will solve for the actuall y value. And then so on...